# MYSQL How can I make dropdown list?

Tags: mysql

I created a new table in workbench where I want to put a season of a soccer championship.

I don't want to write down every time the team's names, can you help me pls, how can I make like a dropdown list (or set of values, what are the only options for that column), when I begin to type "Bay..." its automatically offer "Bayern München" as the only option.

Comment: You can't slash shouldn't do this in pure MySQL. Do you have an application layer you're working with, or are you asking how to do this in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: I have a python code to do different stuff with the data, but first of course I just want to save to data by hand, directly to a table, that's why I thought there is a way for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much will this help, but I have made a dropdown list for something else and I hope my way might give you an idea:

```php
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) //Array or records stored in $row
{ 
    if($row[id]==10) 
    {
        echo "<option value=$row[id] selected>$row[name]</option>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>"; 
    }
}
echo "</select>"; // Closing of list box
```

Comment: If this is PHP then `echo "$row[name]";` doesn't work, you'd need `echo $row[name];` as the interpolation is unneccessary.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for your contribution. Per @tadman's feedback, I've taken the liberty of editing your post to improve the formatting and standardize the indentation. Please review so that you can format your future posts on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As the same answer above, but using short-hand ternary operator instead of if-else statement, and don't forget to use `'` or `"` when reference to object string index.

```php
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) //Array or records stored in $row
{
        printf("<option value='%s' %s>%s</option>", $row['id'], $row['id'] == 10 ? 'selected' : '', $row['name']);
    }
}
echo "</select>"; // Closing of list box
```